# Not able to do any changes in my CRM 2013 on-premise (Customization)(Customize the System)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, sqlexception

I'm using MS CRM 2013 On-Pre, In the Trace file i found below line in error message attribute when trying to delete any field or entity even when trying to add new entity or field.In sort at this time I am not able to do any changes in my CRM.

"**Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #0494EF01**"

How can I analyze the code, Is there any entity where I can find all the error code.

Please suggest I'm totally confused.

Comment: First three things thing I'd check would be (a) disk space on SQL server (b) reboot crm/sql servers (c) creating a new organization and see if the same problems arise. Also, was the organization upgraded from an earlier crm version ?

Comment: Hi @Alex I was removed one entity directly from SQL Server. and suddenly after that it will not working properly. And as per your suggestion I was also reboot the server.

Comment: You probably broke the environment, one should never touch data on SQL directly

Comment: So is there any solutions @Alex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BharatPrajapati `alex` is right, you probably broke the environment.

One should never change `fields` and `Entities` directly in SQL. This is highly un-supported Customizations.

If you had setup daily backups for the `CRM Database`. You can restore the backup on the same `CRM Organization`. It will start working fine. You have to map the security roles etc again.

If you want to delete the the `Entity` which you deleted from SQL you can/should delete that in `CRM`

P.S if you do not have daily backups schedule then there is no solution other than a `New CRM` Installation.